# Showing $\sum |\hat{f}(n)| \leq C \cdot \int_{0}^{2\pi} |f(t)| \ dt$

Tags: functional-analysis

If $f \in L^{1}[0,2\pi]$ define $\hat{f}(n)$ for $n \in\mathbb{Z}$ by $$\hat{f}(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(t) \cdot (\cos(nt) -i\sin(nt)) \ dt$$ Suppose $M$ is a closed linear subspace of $L^{1}[0,2\pi]$ such that $\sum |\hat{f}(n)| < \infty$ for each $f \in M$.Then how can one show that there is a constant $C$ such that $$\sum_{n} |\hat{f}(n)| \leq C \int_{0}^{2\pi} |f(t)| \ dt$$ for each $f \in M$. Can anyone help me out with a clear solution.